# Reset S3a back to S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I use the following to setup s3a to switch role in AWS emr-6.2.0

```
    sparky.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
        "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider",
    )
    sparky.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.access.key", new_credentials["Credentials"]["AccessKeyId"]
    )
    sparky.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.secret.key", new_credentials["Credentials"]["SecretAccessKey"]
    )
    sparky.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set(
        "fs.s3a.session.token", new_credentials["Credentials"]["SessionToken"]
    )
```

the question is how I switch back to access my current role?
Simple solution seems to be:
`spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().clear()`
but that clears all & I get following errors.

```
>>> df_disp_prod = spark.read.csv(
...     "s3://sandboxes-analysis/demo_inventory/distinct_disp_prod_id.tsv",
...     sep=r"\t",
...     header=True,
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 535, in csv
    return self._df(self._jreader.csv(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 128, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o515.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3356)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:123)
```

I used following to get configs:
`>>> _ = [print(conf) for conf in spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()]`

I can get config if I know the name, but is there I can getAll for _jsc.hadoopConfiguration()? So, can store & repopulate the config?

```
configs = [
    "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider",
    "fs.s3a.access.key",
    "fs.s3a.secret.key",
    "fs.s3a.session.token",
]
_ = [print(c, spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().get(c)) for c in configs]
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to just use s3:// URLS to use the EMR s3 connector, and s3a:// to use the apache one, just set the s3a auth details and they ought to coexist.

Clearing the config seems to lose too much information. If you absolutely need to remove an option, you can use `Configuration.unset(key)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().clear()
    spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().reloadConfiguration()
```

Seems to get "s3a://my_sweet_home/prodigal_son_returns"

```
def hadoop_config_dict(spark):
    hadoop_config_d = {
        e.getKey(): e.getValue()
        for e in spark.sparkContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().iterator()
    }
    # Sort by key and return
    return {k: hadoop_config_d[k] for k in sorted(hadoop_config_d)}
```

gets the dictionary of all hadoop configs

Comment: were you able to re-connect with different role ? I am using hadoop 2.7 and spark 2.X with scala . But I am not able to reconnect with hadoop config changed.

Comment: Yes, I was able to. Using 
Release label:emr-6.4.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon
Applications:Spark 3.1.2, JupyterHub 1.4.1